# Comparing real topological K-theory and algebraic K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and let $i$ be a non-negative integer such that $K^i_{alg}(R)$ is finitely generated abelian group. Is it possible that there does not exist weak homotopy type of finite CW complex $X$ such that $KO^i(X)\approx K^i_{alg}(R)$?

Comment: Topological $K$-theory satisfies Bott periodicity, algebraic $K$-theory not.

Comment: @TKe understood, will formulate a weaker question

Comment: For $K_0$ it is true that topological K-theory $K_0$ of a $C^*$-Algebra is the same as algebraic K-theory $K_0$ of the underlying ring. But even then not every ring is a $C^*$-Algebra.

Comment: @ThiKu I am only starting to learn this stuff. Does your remark immediately lead to an explicit counterexample/obstruction?

Comment: @ThiKu That's not true for higher degrees. You need a stability condition: algebraic and topological K-theory of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ coincide if there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{K}\hat\otimes A\cong A$

Comment: Regarding the main question: Bott periodicity is still a powerful obstruction. I don't know if you mean complex or real topological K-theory, but still in general there's no element $u\in K_8(A)$ such that $u:K_i(A)→K_{i+8}(A)$ is an isomorphism for all positive $i$'s. You could potentially try to fix this using *connective* topological K-theory though

Comment: @DenisNardin maybe I am wrong, but won't the element still exist for $i>8$ even if we take connective cover?

Comment: @rori The element still exists, but it's unclear to me why multiplication by it should give an isomorphism. Let me take complex K-theory for simplicity, the fiber sequence $Σ^2ku→ku→H\mathbb{Z}$ shows that there are potential obstructions in integral cohomology to it being an isomorphism

Comment: @DenisNardin on second thought, I am not so sure passing to connective K-theory was necessary. It is true that in algebraic K-theory there is not going to be such $u$, but if we have two space $X_1$, $X_2$ such that $K^i(A)=KO^i(X_1)$, $K^{i+8}(A)=KO^{i+8}(X_2)$ there is not any sort of product between the topological K-theory groups. Basically the question becomes: do there exist obstructions on the abelian group level, rather than ring level?

Comment: For a finite complex $X$, $K_i(X)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. It is probably possible to exhibit any fg ab group. But algebraic $K$-theory is not finitely generated. Eg, $K_1(Q)=Q^\times$, and for $R=F_2[t,e]/e^2$, $K_1(R)\sim R^\times$ is an infinite rank $F_2$-vector space. I think that there is an open conjecture that a smooth complete variety over a finite field has fg $K$-theory. Maybe even if just one of smooth/complete. Example with different flavor: if $E/C$ elliptic curve, $R$ functions on $E-pt$ then $K_0(R)\sim E(C)$.

Comment: @BenWieland is every compact Hausdorff space weakly homotopy equivalent to a finite complex?

Comment: Compact Hausdorff spaces are more general than finite complexes. But beyond finite complexes, there are multiple definitions of the topological $K$-theory of the Cantor set or the Hawaiian earrings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered in the comments.

Comment: @DavidWhite but is there a complete proof/reference to an example of a finitely generated algebraic K-theory group that is not real K-theory of finite CW complex? Comments at this moment of time do not appear to contain it.

Comment: @rori $(S^1)^\mathbb{N}$ is a compact Hausdorff space by Tychonoff's theorem. The fundamental group of this is not finitely generated, as the fundamental group of a finite complex must be.